# Is it possible to attend a bootcamp training in the USA for 3 months on a B1/B2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, business-travel

I have a B1/B2 visa and was wondering

```
Q1) if I can use that to attend a bootcamp training in USA.
```

The training is for 3 months and am also planning to tour around for 2 to 3 weeks.

The answer in this [post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45200/training-for-3-month-and-attending-conference-is-elegible-under-vwp/45246#45246) quotes this:

> Training
>
> Participating in a training program that is not designed primarily to
>   provide employment. Will receive no payment or income from a U.S.
>   based company/entity, other than an expense allowance or expense
>   reimbursement related to traveler’s stay.

```
Q2. How do I explain to the officer at port of entry that this 
    training doesn't give me employment?
```

Also, I have higher priorities back at home - more specifically my old age parents, so I can't afford to spend long time away from my home.

Moreover I am paying for this training and also for food & living expenses. I am not getting any stipend or any sort of payment. I am taking this training on my own interest and am not employed anywhere.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the "bootcamp" is about? It shouldn't be a problem - get some documentation to show it's some thing you pay to attend, not training to (potentially) work for that company in the future.

Comment: also I think that "study" can be an issue if it's, for example, credit towards a formal qualification.

Comment: You have to specify which "bootcamp" this would be